# Capture node.js crash reason

Tags: node.js

I have a script written in node.js, it uses 'net' library and communicates with distant service over tcp. This script is started using 'node script.js >> log.txt' command and everything in that script that is logged using console.log() function gets written to log.txt but sometimes script dies and I cannot find a reason and nothing gets logged in log.txt around the time script crashed.

How can I capture crash reason?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/tlrobinson/long-stack-traces

Comment: Well all my functions inside this script are within try/catch blocks, so this will not log the problem too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's much easier to capture exceptions by splitting `stdout` and `stderr`. Like so:

```
node script.js 1> log.out 2> err.out
```

By default, node logs normal output to stdout, which I believe you are capturing with `>>`.

As noted in the comments, a segmentation fault is a signal put to stderr by the shell, not necessarily your program. See this [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53289/does-segmentation-fault-message-come-under-stderr) answer for other options.

Comment: Wait, what does this have to do with crashes?  When you see "Segmentation fault: 11" you aren't getting any help from the above!

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you have a suggestion for a better example please share @Michael

Answer (score 17):

Couldn't you listen to [`uncaughtException` event](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception). Something along the lines of =>

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

P.S: after that you are adviced to restart process according to this [article from Felix Geisendörfer](http://debuggable.com/posts/node-js-dealing-with-uncaught-exceptions:4c933d54-1428-443c-928d-4e1ecbdd56cb)

Comment: Genius! I was looking for a way to log stack traces to file, and this of course let me do just that! Thanks alot! =D

Comment: Adding this here for the googler who next ventures into this answer.  
catching `process`'s `uncaughtException` event is considered bad practice, as, by this time, node.js process itself is in an undefined state. You should use [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) instead

Comment: Shrik, could you give an example of how to use domains? I wasn't able to get domains to work for uncaught exceptions

Comment: There's been a [falling out over domains](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/66). This answer is better if you rethrow the error you're trapping